# What is the shortest and/or most efficient regex that will match any input string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python's `re` module to filter a lot of data.

I want to have a default filtering regex for when the user does not care, such that **any** input string will match.

I think the shortest and most efficient regex is '`.*?`'.

The user won't care about the actual substring that matches, just that there exists a match.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy in that case you can just use the empty string pattern, `re.search('', message)` will work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest Regex that will

- match any string with `re.search` is `""`
- match any string with `re.match` is `""`
- match any string with `re.fullmatch` is `".*"`

Answer (score 5):

Edit: Charles Duffy came up with a shorter solution: simply `^`. This is shorter, *and* has the nice effect of being easier on performance.

Original answer: Yes, `.*` is the shortest Regex I know of that will match anything - you're saying "zero or more (`*`) of any character (`.`)"

Comment: `^` is shorter, and the OP indicates that it doesn't need to match content within the string, only to trigger on any string.

Comment: No the shortest pattern is `.` obviously. (no need to add an anchor if you want to check there is at least one character). However, I don't see what is the application of this.

Comment: But dot won't match an empty string.